# Python: Code not running during an exception within a loop

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running a python code with a for loop iteration within a for loop, the code is working however, if an exception is thrown the code to execute under exception is not executing and the code loops inifinitely within the except without moving to the main loop

Error Message below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64)
```

Code that I tried:

```py
for _ in range(100):
    print("main loop pass")
    for button in fb_buttons:
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

        try:
            while like_right:
                for right in like_right:
                    right.click()
                break
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])


        except (NoSuchWindowException, ElementNotVisibleException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:

            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            continue
        except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            time.sleep(10)
            refresh.click()
    else:
        time.sleep(5)
        refresh.click()
        print("refreshed")
```

Googling/documentation came up with nothing...and it strikes me as strange that selenium is fine throwing an exception but can't catch it.

Comment: Your description of what is happening is very confusing.  Also, it seems like trouble that you're calling the same line of code in your first **except** block that likely caused the exception in the first place.  I'm not sure what's actually happening, but one thing I wonder is if where you have "continue", maybe you mean "break"? - the continue could very well explain why you're not "moving to the main loop".

Comment: @Steve, I have tried with adding break in the exception, still the code under exception is not executing, basically I am trying to execute a code if exception occurs:

Comment: Here is the code that I changed:

Comment: `except (NoSuchWindowException, ElementNotVisibleException, StaleElementReferenceException) as e:
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            refresh.click()
            break`

Answer (score 1):

This `break` below renders the following line **unreachable**:

```
break
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) # <--- unreachable
```

Here is a small example of what you might be going for, **note** this code throws:

```
sequence = ['first', 'second', 'third']

def run_after_type_error_exception():
    print("runs after type error")

def run_after_index_error_exception():
    print("runs after index error")
```

Without `break`s this code will catch both exceptions on the first iteration. Here you also have a `for-else` block. Note, that after the third iteration this code will `Do something else`.

```
for iteration in range(5):
    for element in sequence:
        try:
            while sequence:
                for character in element:
                    sequence.pop()
                    sequence[1].split() + 1
        except (NameError, TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            print(f"Caught first exception: {e}")
            run_after_type_error_exception()
            # break
        except IndexError as e:
            print(f"Caught exception {e}")
            run_after_index_error_exception()
            # break
    else:
        print("Do something else")
    print(f"Current iteration: {iteration}")
```

Also, note `time.sleep(is_in_seconds)` so if your code behaves similarly to the above code (where it's in the `else` portion ~half of the time), then you'll be `sleep`ing for ~4 minutes *at least*...